# TYPO3 Powermail Email was just disclaimed

Tags: typo3, powermail

In a TYPO3 10.4.33 with Powermail 8.3.3 some sent forms get a reply 'Email was just disclaimed'. This behaviour seems completely random. When comparing the data I can find no reason why some mails are disclaimed and others not. Spam factor of implicated mails is at 0%.
What normally triggers this behaviour? Can't find anything related in the manual.

Tried to reproduce this with several forms but did not get this reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some Microsoft Email server have activated a spam recognition method, which try to follow every link in an mail to identify if the target is evil or not before the receiver can catch some malware.
Problem here is, that if the link to disclaim is clicked by the automatism of the email server, the mail was just disclaimed.

Possible solutions:

- The email server admin could turn of the "spam recognition" function
- You or your agency can develop a middleware in TYPO3 to catch those requests before powermail
- Disable disclaimer links in powermail
- You or your agency can develop an individual disclaimer function. E.g. the link in the mail redirects to a page where a button "really disclaim" is shown

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and explanation! I will start by disabling the disclaimer-link and see what happens.